# Are features optional or not in an Eclipse e4 application/plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to understand the concept of eclipse `e4` for RCP.
After reading following the tutorial, I am stuck in the following:
Assume I create a `Plugin` project (no Rich Client unchecked, Actvator unchecked so no classes under /src etc)
A plugin is the smallest deployable and installable software components of Eclipse. Ok.
Now I can create a `Product Configuration` which is based on `Plugins` **or** `Features`.
So the `Product Configuration` delivers the plugin etc and if I understand correctly the `Feature` is optional. Assuming that I am correct (don't know, am I?) I add to the product configuration the dependencies:
`org.eclipse.emf.common` and `org.eclipse.emf.ecore` and press `Add Required Plugins`
My product confuration is selected to be **plugin based**.
What I don't understand at this point, is that if I don't define as part of the dependencies *my plugin*, I get a missing plugin when I run the application (I have checked the validate plugins before run). But why? The plugin, has already been defined as a "Definining Plugin" in product definition (New). Why do I have to explicitely add it also here?

Anyway passing that, when I try to launch a window (yes I have created a `New Application Model` and defined a `Trimmed Window`) I get runtime exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: org.eclipse.equinox.app.error.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
```

I can only assume that this happens because a plugin is missing which is:  `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt` (I got this due to enabling validation of plugins)

[image]

Why do I get this exception? I believe that I get it because I have not added the `org.eclipse.e4.rcp` as dependency.
But I can not find it as an option. Turns out that this is available to be selected only if the product configuration is `based on Features`. It is not available for Plugins.
Additionally the same process but defining a `Feature` and "attach" it as dependency to the product configuration works! I.e. no runtime exception and the window shows up.

So what is happening? Are features mandatory? I don't understand. I thought they are optional. Could anyone help me figure this out?

**Update:**
If I manually add `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt` as dependency (and press add required) in the `product` I get:

[image]

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-08-20 18:36:52.044
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-08-20 18:36:52.044
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt_0.10.1.v20120525-2014.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt 2 0 2012-08-20 18:36:52.044
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.databinding_[1.2.0,2.0.0).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are creating a plugin based product on Eclipse 4, you still need most of the plugins that comprise the org.eclipse.e4.rcp feature.  Try adding them from the list in http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/tree/features/org.eclipse.e4.rcp/feature.xml

Comment: So the problem is indeed the fact that the `org.eclipse.e4.rcp` is missing?Ok I will try what you say, but why does it only work if the `product` is based on `Features`.According to http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/concepts/product.htm `Feature` is optional

Comment: You were right.There were 4-5 missing from the the `product->Dependencies Tab` that were as part of this list you posted in your answer.Sorry I am new in eclipse development.What does this mean?That the `Feature` is optional but I would have to add all these manually in order to work?So the recommended approach is to always use a `Feature`? Never plugin based?

Comment: I mean after adding the extra components the Window opens with no errors

Comment: Product definitions can work using plugins only, but eclipse SDK itself uses features so that's what it is geared towards.

Comment: And I am using eclipse SDK, and so I `must` also use features I guess you are saying.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that.  I'm just say features are installable units of functionality in the eclipse world.  They make it easier to build, install, and update products, and that's what eclipse itself uses.  But you can build products out of bundles directly, you are just taking the place of features (you have to track down all of the correct bundles yourself).